# Reversing Grouped Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I apologise in advance if this is a duplicate. 
I have looked at this question, yet have been unable to figure out how to use it when it's not nested: [Link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208164/reversing-a-groupby-operation).
I have a grouped list of random words

```
    list = <|"Net1" -> {{"counteroffensive", "nonpayment", 
     "dieresis"}, {"suffragan", "identifiably"}}, 
  "Net2" -> {{"psychiatrist", "pusher", "generous", "praising", 
     "thy"}, {"amplification", "amylase", "shooting", "tumbler", 
     "mimosa", "dengue"}}|>
```

And the output should be:

```
    output = {
<|"Net1" -> {"counteroffensive", "nonpayment", 
     "dieresis"}|>, 
<|"Net1" -> {"suffragan", 
     "identifiably"}|>, 
<|"Net2" -> {"psychiatrist", "pusher", 
     "generous", "praising", "thy"}|>, 
<|"Net2" -> {"amplification", 
     "amylase", "shooting", "tumbler", "mimosa", "dengue"}|>}
```

Much appreciated for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
KeyValueMap[Thread[#1 -> #2] &, list] // Flatten // Map[Association]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Association /@ Flatten[Table[Thread[key -> list[key]], {key, Keys[list]}], 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using ideas from [this answer by Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208165/125):

```
unMerge = Catenate @* MapIndexed[Association /@ Thread[#2[[1, 1]] -> #] &];

unmerged = unMerge @ list
```

> {<|"Net1" -> {"counteroffensive", "nonpayment", 
>       "dieresis"}|>,
>   <|"Net1" -> {"suffragan", 
>       "identifiably"}|>,
>    <|"Net2" -> {"psychiatrist", "pusher", 
>       "generous", "praising", "thy"}|>,
>   <|"Net2" -> {"amplification", 
>       "amylase", "shooting", "tumbler", "mimosa", "dengue"}|>}

```
Merge[Identity] @ unmerged  == list
```

> True

Another way to use `MapIndexed`:

```
unMerge2 = Map[Association] @* Catenate @* MapIndexed[Thread[#2[[1, 1]] -> #] &];

unMerge @ list == unMerge2 @ list
```

> True

Also:

```
unMerge3 = Query[Catenate @* Map[KeyValueMap[Association @* Rule]] @* Transpose];

Sort @ unMerge @ list == Sort @ unMerge3 @ list
```

> True

If the output from `` GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose `` is acceptable, you can also use:

```
Query[Transpose] @ list
```

> {<|"Net1" -> {"counteroffensive", "nonpayment", "dieresis"}, 
>     "Net2" -> {"psychiatrist", "pusher", "generous", "praising", 
>       "thy"}|>,
>    <|"Net1" -> {"suffragan", "identifiably"}, 
>     "Net2" -> {"amplification", "amylase", "shooting", "tumbler", 
>       "mimosa", "dengue"}|>}

Comment: `Curry` can make `Query` example more concise; `Query[KeyValueMap[Curry[Association@*Rule, 2]@# /@ #2 &] /* 
   Catenate]@list` .

Comment: Thank you @Edmund; that's much nicer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AssociationTranspose`,

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
AssociationTranspose[list]
(* 
    {
        <|
            "Net1" -> {"counteroffensive", "nonpayment", "dieresis"},
            "Net2" -> {"psychiatrist", "pusher", "generous", "praising", "thy"}
        |>,
        <|
            "Net1" -> {"suffragan", "identifiably"},
            "Net2" -> {"amplification", "amylase", "shooting", "tumbler", "mimosa", "dengue"}
        |>
    }
*)
```

which is very close to the output desired in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Shortest yet?

```
<|#|> & /@ Join @@ Thread /@ Normal[list]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about key order, transposing a `Dataset` gives you what you want, it just needs a catenation of association rules and transforming it back to list with `Normal`:

```
Dataset[list][Transpose /* Normal /* Catenate] // Normal
```